# median imputation or case deletion for small samples

Tags: anova, data-imputation

I have a dilemma. I have a data set of different proteins from 4 groups of animals characterized by two factors: age (3 or 12 months) and presence of a certain gene (KO or WT). For each combination of factors (3m, KO; 12m KO; 3m WT; 12m WT) I have 6 measurements (i.e., 6 animals), except for one group of which I have only 5 measurements. This prevents me from conducting an Aligned Rank Transform to then perform a nonparametric factorial (ANOVA) analysis. Instead, the analysis technically works if (a) I reduce the samples to 5 data points per group, or (b) if I replace the missing data point with the median of the 5 data points of the same group. I really don't know which one is the better solution.

Comment: Neither option is great imho. I'm a bit confused about the study design. Can you describe it in more detail ? How many animals do you have in total ? Are the animals measured multiple times ? What are you measuring, and what is your research question ?

Comment: It's a proteomic study carried out in 24 mice of 3/12 months and with/without a certain gene, following a 2x2 factor design, with 6 animals per group. Because of not normal distributions we planned to apply ARTool to correct ranks for a nonparametric ANOVA. But unfortunately one animal was lost. I tried to circumvent the problem (a) reducing all the groups to 5 animals or (b) replacing the single missing value with the group median. In both cases data were correctly processed but with different outputs. I would ask which of the two methods (data deletion or median substitution) is preferable.

Comment: There may be other alternatives but I haven't fully understood the design yet. What is it that you are measuring ? What is the research question/hypothesis ?

Comment: We measured the 'abundance' of about 2000 different proteins in two brain regions of mice of different age and expressing o not the SPPL2B gene, which is important for the development of innate immunity. The nonparametric factor ANOVA was intended to verify the effect of age, that of SPPL2B, and possible interactions, on each of the 2000 proteins.

Comment: Thanks for the further information. So I assume this "'abundance' of about 2000 different proteins" has some kind of summary measure and this is your dependent variable ? If you set the problem up as a regression model, I suspect the unbalanced groups issue may not be a problem, but to be honest I'm still not fully understanding the design yet.

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Comment: PLease add this extra information as an edit to the post, not only as comments! We want posts to be self-contained, and comments can be removed, and are often only seen by very few people.

Comment: In addition to the points raised by @RobertLong, it seems to me that you have repeated measures and need to account for this. I suggest a multilevel model; these deal well with drop out.